# How can I make people stop freaking out when I drive?

Tags: watch-dogs

So, when I'm driving around, people will freak out, run away from me, yell at me, or curse at me even when I'm not driving on the sidewalk. I don't really follow traffic laws, because it would take too long to get to where I am going, so I regularly speed, run red lights/stop signs, lane split (in a car), drive on the wrong side of the street, and otherwise drive somewhat recklessly, but even when I am driving "normally" people still get scared of me. Can I prevent people from freaking out when I drive, or do they always cower in fear due to me being a vigilante or something?

Comment: HNQ nominee here.